# Implement shared memory segment with a_list struct (linked list in shared memory) in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I need to make a shared memory segment that holds nodes using this struct that I made

```
struct a_list
{
  //The head of the list that acts as a node, this list has a next* and a prev*
  struct list_head list;
  unsigned long*   val;
  char* str;
  char state;
};
```

I tried looking up answers on stack but they implemented a Node as opposed to my struct, which is a list with nodes inside

I also have this buffer and append method which I used to append to this list (using malloc) but I know that for shared memory I cannot do that

```
struct buffer
{
    struct a_list* buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int in;
    int out;
};
//Method to append a file to the end of the queue (Most recently used files are at the tail)
static void append(struct a_list* ptr,const char* str, unsigned long val)           
{
  struct a_list* tmp;
  tmp = (struct a_list*)malloc(sizeof(struct a_list));

 // tmp->str = str;
  tmp->str = (char *)malloc(strlen(str)+1);
  strcpy(tmp->str, str);
  tmp->val = (unsigned long*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
  memcpy(tmp->val, &val, sizeof(unsigned long));
  tmp->index = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  memcpy(tmp->index, &buffer_p->in, sizeof(int));
  tmp->address = (struct a_list*)malloc(sizeof(struct a_list*));
  memcpy(tmp->address, &fileQueue, sizeof(struct a_list*));
  if(list_empty(&fileQueue.list)){ //If this is the first element to be inserted into the fileQueue, initialize the head
    list_add_tail( &(tmp->list), &(ptr->list) );
    head = list_entry(fileQueue.list.next,struct a_list, list);
  }
  else{ //Else just add it to the tail of the list
    list_add_tail( &(tmp->list), &(ptr->list) );
  }
 // while(((buffer_p->in+1)%BUFFER_SIZE) == buffer_p->out)
    //      ;

  buffer_p->buffer[buffer_p->in] = tmp->address;
        //printf("Placed: %d\n", counter);

  buffer_p->in = (buffer_p->in+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

and In my main I try to initialize everything with

```
if ((shmid = shmget(key, (BUFFER_SIZE+2)*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((shm = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    buffer_p = (struct buffer*) shm;
    buffer_p->in = 0;
    buffer_p->out = 0;
```

which I don't like how this is working because im making a pointer to something that's been malloc'd (which won't work with shared memory) so I want to change it so that it will actually work with shared memory. I have used Beej's Guide on shared memory as a guide as well as several stack overflow questions but none seem to give me this specific case ( or at least I don't understand the answer). Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just a concept im possibly missing. The list_head struct in the a_list struct (fileQueue) is a struct from a header file referencing the kernel linked list implementation.

EDIT: Here is the list_head struct that's being used in this program, it's basically using the kernel implementation of a list

```
/**
 * 
 * I grub it from linux kernel source code and fix it for user space
 * program. Of course, this is a GPL licensed header file.
 *
 * Here is a recipe to cook list.h for user space program
 *
 * 1. copy list.h from linux/include/list.h
 * 2. remove 
 *     - #ifdef __KERNE__ and its #endif
 *     - all #include line
 *     - prefetch() and rcu related functions
 * 3. add macro offsetof() and container_of
 *
 * - kazutomo@mcs.anl.gov
 */
#ifndef _LINUX_LIST_H
#define _LINUX_LIST_H

/**
 * @name from other kernel headers
 */
/*@{*/

/**
 * Get offset of a member
 */
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)

/**
 * Casts a member of a structure out to the containing structure
 * @param ptr        the pointer to the member.
 * @param type       the type of the container struct this is embedded in.
 * @param member     the name of the member within the struct.
 *
 */
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
/*@}*/


/*
 * These are non-NULL pointers that will result in page faults
 * under normal circumstances, used to verify that nobody uses
 * non-initialized list entries.
 */
#define LIST_POISON1  ((void *) 0x00100100)
#define LIST_POISON2  ((void *) 0x00200200)

/**
 * Simple doubly linked list implementation.
 *
 * Some of the internal functions ("__xxx") are useful when
 * manipulating whole lists rather than single entries, as
 * sometimes we already know the next/prev entries and we can
 * generate better code by using them directly rather than
 * using the generic single-entry routines.
 */
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};

#define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name) { &(name), &(name) }

#define LIST_HEAD(name) \
    struct list_head name = LIST_HEAD_INIT(name)

#define INIT_LIST_HEAD(ptr) do { \
    (ptr)->next = (ptr); (ptr)->prev = (ptr); \
} while (0)

/*
 * Insert a new entry between two known consecutive entries.
 *
 * This is only for internal list manipulation where we know
 * the prev/next entries already!
 */
static inline void __list_add(struct list_head *new,
                  struct list_head *prev,
                  struct list_head *next)
{
    next->prev = new;
    new->next = next;
    new->prev = prev;
    prev->next = new;
}

/**
 * list_add - add a new entry
 * @new: new entry to be added
 * @head: list head to add it after
 *
 * Insert a new entry after the specified head.
 * This is good for implementing stacks.
 */
static inline void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_add(new, head, head->next);
}

/**
 * list_add_tail - add a new entry
 * @new: new entry to be added
 * @head: list head to add it before
 *
 * Insert a new entry before the specified head.
 * This is useful for implementing queues.
 */
static inline void list_add_tail(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_add(new, head->prev, head);
}


/*
 * Delete a list entry by making the prev/next entries
 * point to each other.
 *
 * This is only for internal list manipulation where we know
 * the prev/next entries already!
 */
static inline void __list_del(struct list_head * prev, struct list_head * next)
{
    next->prev = prev;
    prev->next = next;
}

/**
 * list_del - deletes entry from list.
 * @entry: the element to delete from the list.
 * Note: list_empty on entry does not return true after this, the entry is
 * in an undefined state.
 */
static inline void list_del(struct list_head *entry)
{
    __list_del(entry->prev, entry->next);
    entry->next = LIST_POISON1;
    entry->prev = LIST_POISON2;
}



/**
 * list_del_init - deletes entry from list and reinitialize it.
 * @entry: the element to delete from the list.
 */
static inline void list_del_init(struct list_head *entry)
{
    __list_del(entry->prev, entry->next);
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(entry);
}

/**
 * list_move - delete from one list and add as another's head
 * @list: the entry to move
 * @head: the head that will precede our entry
 */
static inline void list_move(struct list_head *list, struct list_head *head)
{
        __list_del(list->prev, list->next);
        list_add(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_move_tail - delete from one list and add as another's tail
 * @list: the entry to move
 * @head: the head that will follow our entry
 */
static inline void list_move_tail(struct list_head *list,
                  struct list_head *head)
{
        __list_del(list->prev, list->next);
        list_add_tail(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_empty - tests whether a list is empty
 * @head: the list to test.
 */
static inline int list_empty(const struct list_head *head)
{
    return head->next == head;
}

static inline void __list_splice(struct list_head *list,
                 struct list_head *head)
{
    struct list_head *first = list->next;
    struct list_head *last = list->prev;
    struct list_head *at = head->next;

    first->prev = head;
    head->next = first;

    last->next = at;
    at->prev = last;
}

/**
 * list_splice - join two lists
 * @list: the new list to add.
 * @head: the place to add it in the first list.
 */
static inline void list_splice(struct list_head *list, struct list_head *head)
{
    if (!list_empty(list))
        __list_splice(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_splice_init - join two lists and reinitialise the emptied list.
 * @list: the new list to add.
 * @head: the place to add it in the first list.
 *
 * The list at @list is reinitialised
 */
static inline void list_splice_init(struct list_head *list,
                    struct list_head *head)
{
    if (!list_empty(list)) {
        __list_splice(list, head);
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(list);
    }
}

/**
 * list_entry - get the struct for this entry
 * @ptr:    the &struct list_head pointer.
 * @type:   the type of the struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    container_of(ptr, type, member)

/**
 * list_for_each    -   iterate over a list
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 */

#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
  for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head);   \
       pos = pos->next)

/**
 * __list_for_each  -   iterate over a list
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 *
 * This variant differs from list_for_each() in that it's the
 * simplest possible list iteration code, no prefetching is done.
 * Use this for code that knows the list to be very short (empty
 * or 1 entry) most of the time.
 */
#define __list_for_each(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)

/**
 * list_for_each_prev   -   iterate over a list backwards
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each_prev(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->prev; prefetch(pos->prev), pos != (head); \
            pos = pos->prev)

/**
 * list_for_each_safe   -   iterate over a list safe against removal of list entry
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another &struct list_head to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each_safe(pos, n, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next, n = pos->next; pos != (head); \
        pos = n, n = pos->next)

/**
 * list_for_each_entry  -   iterate over list of given type
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)              \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member);  \
         pos->member != (head);                 \
         pos = list_entry(pos->member->next, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_reverse - iterate backwards over list of given type.
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_reverse(pos, head, member)          \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->prev, typeof(*pos), member);  \
         &pos->member != (head);    \
         pos = list_entry(pos->member.prev, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_prepare_entry - prepare a pos entry for use as a start point in
 *          list_for_each_entry_continue
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a start point
 * @head:   the head of the list
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_prepare_entry(pos, head, member) \
    ((pos) ? : list_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_continue -   iterate over list of given type
 *          continuing after existing point
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_continue(pos, head, member)         \
    for (pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member);  \
         &pos->member != (head);    \
         pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_safe - iterate over list of given type safe against removal of list entry
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another type * to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_safe(pos, n, head, member)          \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member),  \
        n = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member); \
         &pos->member != (head);                    \
         pos = n, n = list_entry(n->member.next, typeof(*n), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_safe_continue -  iterate over list of given type
 *          continuing after existing point safe against removal of list entry
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another type * to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_safe_continue(pos, n, head, member)         \
    for (pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member),      \
        n = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member);     \
         &pos->member != (head);                        \
         pos = n, n = list_entry(n->member.next, typeof(*n), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_safe_reverse - iterate backwards over list of given type safe against
 *                    removal of list entry
 * @pos:    the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another type * to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_safe_reverse(pos, n, head, member)      \
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->prev, typeof(*pos), member),  \
        n = list_entry(pos->member.prev, typeof(*pos), member); \
         &pos->member != (head);                    \
         pos = n, n = list_entry(n->member.prev, typeof(*n), member))




/*
 * Double linked lists with a single pointer list head.
 * Mostly useful for hash tables where the two pointer list head is
 * too wasteful.
 * You lose the ability to access the tail in O(1).
 */

struct hlist_head {
    struct hlist_node *first;
};

struct hlist_node {
    struct hlist_node *next, **pprev;
};

#define HLIST_HEAD_INIT { .first = NULL }
#define HLIST_HEAD(name) struct hlist_head name = {  .first = NULL }
#define INIT_HLIST_HEAD(ptr) ((ptr)->first = NULL)
#define INIT_HLIST_NODE(ptr) ((ptr)->next = NULL, (ptr)->pprev = NULL)

static inline int hlist_unhashed(const struct hlist_node *h)
{
    return !h->pprev;
}

static inline int hlist_empty(const struct hlist_head *h)
{
    return !h->first;
}

static inline void __hlist_del(struct hlist_node *n)
{
    struct hlist_node *next = n->next;
    struct hlist_node **pprev = n->pprev;
    *pprev = next;
    if (next)
        next->pprev = pprev;
}

static inline void hlist_del(struct hlist_node *n)
{
    __hlist_del(n);
    n->next = LIST_POISON1;
    n->pprev = LIST_POISON2;
}


static inline void hlist_del_init(struct hlist_node *n)
{
    if (n->pprev)  {
        __hlist_del(n);
        INIT_HLIST_NODE(n);
    }
}

static inline void hlist_add_head(struct hlist_node *n, struct hlist_head *h)
{
    struct hlist_node *first = h->first;
    n->next = first;
    if (first)
        first->pprev = &n->next;
    h->first = n;
    n->pprev = &h->first;
}



/* next must be != NULL */
static inline void hlist_add_before(struct hlist_node *n,
                    struct hlist_node *next)
{
    n->pprev = next->pprev;
    n->next = next;
    next->pprev = &n->next;
    *(n->pprev) = n;
}

static inline void hlist_add_after(struct hlist_node *n,
                    struct hlist_node *next)
{
    next->next = n->next;
    n->next = next;
    next->pprev = &n->next;

    if(next->next)
        next->next->pprev  = &next->next;
}



#define hlist_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr,type,member)

#define hlist_for_each(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->first; pos && ({ prefetch(pos->next); 1; }); \
         pos = pos->next)

#define hlist_for_each_safe(pos, n, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->first; pos && ({ n = pos->next; 1; }); \
         pos = n)

/**
 * hlist_for_each_entry - iterate over list of given type
 * @tpos:   the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @pos:    the &struct hlist_node to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
 */
#define hlist_for_each_entry(tpos, pos, head, member)            \
    for (pos = (head)->first;                    \
         pos && ({ prefetch(pos->next); 1;}) &&          \
        ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
         pos = pos->next)

/**
 * hlist_for_each_entry_continue - iterate over a hlist continuing after existing point
 * @tpos:   the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @pos:    the &struct hlist_node to use as a loop counter.
 * @member: the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
 */
#define hlist_for_each_entry_continue(tpos, pos, member)         \
    for (pos = (pos)->next;                      \
         pos && ({ prefetch(pos->next); 1;}) &&          \
        ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
         pos = pos->next)

/**
 * hlist_for_each_entry_from - iterate over a hlist continuing from existing point
 * @tpos:   the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @pos:    the &struct hlist_node to use as a loop counter.
 * @member: the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
 */
#define hlist_for_each_entry_from(tpos, pos, member)             \
    for (; pos && ({ prefetch(pos->next); 1;}) &&            \
        ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
         pos = pos->next)

/**
 * hlist_for_each_entry_safe - iterate over list of given type safe against removal of list entry
 * @tpos:   the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @pos:    the &struct hlist_node to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:      another &struct hlist_node to use as temporary storage
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 * @member: the name of the hlist_node within the struct.
 */
#define hlist_for_each_entry_safe(tpos, pos, n, head, member)        \
    for (pos = (head)->first;                    \
         pos && ({ n = pos->next; 1; }) &&               \
        ({ tpos = hlist_entry(pos, typeof(*tpos), member); 1;}); \
         pos = n)


#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my workaround:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#define MAX_SHM_ID_NUM 100

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node;
int shm_id_arr[MAX_SHM_ID_NUM];
int current_index = -1 ;

void insert_at_tail (int num);
node * my_head = NULL;
int * num_of_elements = NULL ;

key_t key_first = 5681;
key_t key_current;

void *  my_malloc(int size)
{
    void * ptr = NULL;
    key_current = key_first ++;
    int shm_id;
    if ((shm_id = shmget(key_current, size , IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget error.");printf("errno= %d EINVAL=%d \n ", errno , EINVAL);
       return NULL;
    }

    if ((ptr = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == (void *) - 1) {
        perror("shmat error");
        //exit(1);
        return NULL;

    }
    current_index ++ ;
    shm_id_arr[current_index] = shm_id ;
    return ptr;

}

void insert_at_tail (int num)
{
    if(my_head == NULL)
    {
        my_head = my_malloc(sizeof(node));
        my_head->val = num;
        my_head->next = NULL;

    }else
    {
        node * tmp = my_head;
        while(tmp->next != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = my_malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->next->val = num;
        tmp->next->next = NULL;
    }
    (* num_of_elements) ++;
}
/* deAttach the shared memory without removing. */
void deattach_shared_mem()
{

   if (shmdt(num_of_elements) < 0) { /*  deAttach  num_of_elements */
       perror("shmdt error num_of_elements\n");

   }

   if (shmdt(my_head) < 0) {
       perror("shmdt error my_head\n");
   }


   //how to deattach all pointers in list?
}
void remove_shared_mem()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < current_index ; i ++)
    {
        if (shmctl(shm_id_arr[i], IPC_RMID, NULL) < 0) { /* remove the shared memory segment. */
            perror("shmctl error.\n");

        }
    }

}

void print_it()
{
    node * tmp = my_head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n" , tmp->val);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    num_of_elements = (int *)my_malloc(sizeof(int));
    (* num_of_elements) = 0 ;
    insert_at_tail(10);
    insert_at_tail(8);
    insert_at_tail(6);
    insert_at_tail(4);
    insert_at_tail(2);

    printf("we have %d elements.\n" , (*num_of_elements));

    print_it();
    deattach_shared_mem();
    remove_shared_mem();


    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: could you possibly explain with some comments? I'm still having a hard time trying to understand all the logic going on in this example.

Comment: @user1336369 : focus on the primary idea that we must use my_malloc instead of malloc when we want memory to be allocated in shared memory.

Comment: I ended making some minor modifications to the structure but I got it to work :) thank you, this really helps

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should probably to create surrogates for `malloc()` and `free()` (and maybe `realloc()` too) that manage memory allocation from the shared memory instead of the normal heap memory.  You can debug them separately from most of the rest of the code. They will need to know how big the chunk of shared memory is as a whole, and will need to record either what is allocated or what is free (or both). If the memory is shared between processes, the control information needs to be in the shared memory too (otherwise only one process can modify the memory allocations), and you need proper concurrency control (mutexes, etc) to protect it.  If the memory isn't shared between processes, you shouldn't be using shared memory in the first place.

With those primitives in place, you can then revise your code to use them for memory allocation in your code when you need to allocate space.

Note that your code allocates an one `unsigned long` to be pointed at by the `val` member of `struct a_list`.  That is pretty pointless.  You are simply wasting space using a pointer instead an `unsigned long` directly stored in the structure.  It would be a different matter if it was an array of `unsigned long`, but that isn't what you show.

Your question also shows access to an `index` member of the `struct a_list` which isn't shown in the definition of the structure.  And you don't show the `struct list_head` type.  This means people cannot compile your code to observe whether there are other problems.  Making compilable code is a good idea. It is worth spending the time to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, i'm going to change it to a regular unsigned int then, I edit also to include what the struct list_head is